# What's "set -- "$progname" "$@"" means in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

I current read this line from our configure.ac build script. I have search on Google for answer but not find it.

I assume it is shell script but what does this means, especially for `--` ?

```
set -- "$progname" "$@"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `--` is a bash built-in as well as something a lot of unix commands use to denote the end of command options. So if you have something like:

```
grep -- -v file
```

the `-v` won't be interpreted as a grep option, but a parameter (so you can grep for `-v`).

The `$@` is the list of all the parameters that are passed into the script (which I assume the `set` command is a part of).

The `--` ensures that whatever options passed in as part of the script won't get interpreted as options for `set`, but as options for the command denoted by the `$progname` variable.

Answer (score 11):

From `help set`:

> ```
>   --  Assign any remaining arguments to the positional parameters.
>       If there are no remaining arguments, the positional parameters
>       are unset.
> ```

The reason for `--` is to ensure that even if `"$progname"` or `"$@"` contain dashes, they will not be interpreted as command line options.

`set` changes the positional parameters, which is stored in `$@`. So in this case, it appends  `"$progname"` to the beginning of the positional parameters received by the script.